# Stop regex matching part of a word within a word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
if(preg_match(/(www|co.uk|uk.com|com|net|edu|org|org.uk|info|me|biz|co|io)/, $hostParts)) {

    //unset this element from the array;

}
```

I am using a regular expression to remove common domain extensions. The problem I have is my expression also matches the net in cnet in the example of www.cnet.com. How can I stop it matching parts of words for example domains like www.cnet.com as for this this I only want to remove the www and com parts. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, `\b` does a great part of what you want. Inbound your word with two `\b`s. `but check the updates for your specific case`.

```
if(preg_match('/\b(www|co.uk|uk.com|com|net|edu|org|org.uk|info|me|biz|co|io)\b/si', $hostParts)) {

    //unset this element from the array;

}
```

**UPDATE**

This is an update, this is specific for URLs, I didn't take that into consideration:

```
if(preg_match('/(\bwww\.|(\.(co\.uk|uk\.com|com|net|edu|org|org.uk|info|me|biz|co|io)\b))/si', $hostParts)) {

    //unset this element from the array;

}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is an example, note that I've swapped "org" with "org.uk" because if the first was caught the second won't be:

```
<?php

  $str = 'www.cnet.org.uk';
  $str = preg_replace('/(\bwww\.|(\.(co\.uk|uk\.com|com|net|edu|org.uk|org|info|me|biz|co|io)\b))/si', '', $str);
  echo $str;

?>
```

Comment: Thank you this does exactly what I needed. I'm new to regular expressions and only just getting the hang of them.

Comment: Please check the final one, with the example. And it has something swapped.